# Android huge JSONObject toString goes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, json, sqlite, out-of-memory, tostring

I need to read a lot of data from a SQLite database and create a properly formatted JSON.

I'm currently achieving this by having an object called `RequestPayload` which contains some `ArrayList`s in which I put the data I read from SQLite.

The `RequestPayload` class has a `parseJson()` method which returns a `JSONObject` on which I eventually call the `toString()` method to obtain my JSON String that finally got written on a file.

### The Problem

Now, when I've got "small" quantities of data in SQLite everything goes fine. When I've got a lot of data this is what happens:

```
06-28 09:55:34.121 10857-6799/it.example.sampler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-195240
    Process: it.example.sampler, PID: 10857
    Theme: themes:{com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet=overlay:system, com.android.settings=overlay:system, default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52962812 byte allocation with 16764752 free bytes and 41MB until OOM
      at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
      at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:629)
      at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
      at org.json.JSONStringer.toString(JSONStringer.java:430)
      at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:690)
      at it.example.sampler.controllers.network.RequestBodyEncoder.serialise(RequestBodyEncoder.java:69)
      at it.example.sampler.controllers.network.RequestBodyEncoder.createPacket(RequestBodyEncoder.java:50)
      at it.example.sampler.services.FileStoreRunnable.run(FileStoreRunnable.java:57)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

06-28 09:55:34.509 10857-10857/it.example.sampler E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity it.example.sampler.ui.StartSamplingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{74710d V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,494} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:372)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
    at it.example.sampler.ui.StartSamplingActivity.executeStop(StartSamplingActivity.java:305)
    at it.example.sampler.ui.StartSamplingActivity.onClickedButton(StartSamplingActivity.java:256)
    at it.example.sampler.ui.StartSamplingActivity$3.onClick(StartSamplingActivity.java:190)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

### The Code

the error line is from this method:

```
private String serialise() throws JSONException {
    // Serialise
    String sampleString = mPayload.parseJSON().toString(); // THIS LINE

    Logger.get().d(LOG_TAG, "Serialised payload: -> " + sampleString);
    return sampleString;
}
```

and if I got the LogCat correctly the error is during the execution of the `toString()` method and it appears that the JSON object is too big.

How can I handle this situation?

---

**UPDATE:**
To answer to @YashJain comment asking for the size of the JSONObject.

After sampling a sampling lasted 2 hours I had a JSON containing:

- **12** JSONArray containing 155.432 `float`s
- **2** JSONArray containing 8.393 `float`s
- **1** JSONArray containing 8.393 custom object containing 5 `float`s each (and a String)
- **1** 2D array containing 155.432 `int`s

In terms of bytes since a Float is made by 4 bytes (I hope I've done the calculus correctly) I've got circa:

```
(12 * 155432 * 4) + (2 * 8393 * 4) + (1 * 8393 * 5) + (1 * 155432 * 4) ~= 8.191.573 bytes
```

**UPDATE:**
I've been asked about the used compression algorithm. I use `ZLIB` via the `Deflater` and `DeflaterOutputStream` Java classes.

Thus the flow is:

- Sample data -> Store them in `SQLite`
- Read from `SQLite` -> Build `RequestPayload` object in memory
- Convert `RequestPayload` object to `JSONObject` (with a custom parser).
- Convert the `JSONObject` to String (using `JSONObject` `toString()` method)
- Compress the String bytes (using `getBytes()`) -> encode it in Base64
- Send final Base64 string to server

**EDIT:**
To address to the "possibile duplicate flag" I haven't seen that question during my researches by the way that didn't help me since it makes use of `largeHeap` directive (which I don't use). Also there's no accepted answer and the only answer doesn't actually provide a practical solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONObject.toString() returns OutOfMemoryError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919833/jsonobject-tostring-returns-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: I dunno the answer, but I wanna know how large data is it able to hold? Like how many bytes/characters.

Comment: @mdDroid I've added an edit explaining why I don't thing the "possibile duplicate" flag might help.. anyway thanks for flagging because I haven't seen it while researching before asking the question.. sadly it didn't help

Comment: @YashJain I've added an update with some calculations... I'm counting only the primitive types since I can't do it programmatically right now because I need to make the app run for 2 hours :)

Comment: If you can't compromise from space, why not from speed? You can parse and display data by splitting it into a few parts right?

Comment: The generated JSON goes to a file? So it is possible to get away with [streaming to the file directly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html) or do you need the JSON string also elsewhere?

Comment: @GoktayKaykusuz thanks for the tip.. splitting the arrays is actually a possibile solution I've thought about but i'm keeping it as my last chance.. Since I can't allocate too much efforts on this fix I hope to find an easier (to implement) solution.

Comment: @dhke Thanks for the resource, I'll read it and try to use it tomorrow, I'll let you know :) btw: yes, it goes on a file.. but I actually need the JSON string before the write to apply on it a compression algorithm.. Anyway, I guess that storing it in a temporary file, deallocate resources and then load the string from the file and compress it might be a possibile solution, right?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski Well, if the compression algorithm also accepts streaming data, you might be able to stream compressed data to the file. What type of compression do you need (i.e. which library)?

Comment: @dhke I've added an update with informations about the compression.. Yeah, I'm using input/output streamers with `Deflate` Java class.. hence I think this solution might be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not giving any more feedbacks I've been busy with other works and this got last in my priority queue.

Anyhow what actually worked for me is using `Google GSON` library.

My serialisation method has become simply:

```
private String serialise() {
    // Serialise
    return mPayload.toStringFromGSON();
}
```

And method `toStringFromGSON()` in class `Payload` is:

```
public String toStringFromGSON() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    return gson.toJson(this);
}
```

---

Anyhow I think this can be considered only a temporary patch. In fact I noticed that the memory used by the application increases dramatically during this phase hence I think the problem is only postponed and it will eventually occur with heavier loads..

Answer (score 0):

Your Qn is  very good.
Did you try by putting in `AsyncTask` maybe it will work by `Thread` handling.

```
private String serialise() throws JSONException {
    String sampleString = "";

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground( Void... voids ) {
            // Serialise
            sampleString = mPayload.parseJSON().toString(); // THIS LINE.
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    Logger.get().d(LOG_TAG, "Serialised payload: -> " + sampleString);
    return sampleString;
}
```

I assume you have good knowledge.
Sorry if it might doesn't work. But it did in my case. Please check it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, actually this job is implemented inside a `Runnable` implementation and runs on a different `Thread` like this:
 `new Thread(new FileStoreRunnable(getApplicationContext(), mHandler)).start();`

Answer (score 0):

You ever will have the problem on huge Jsons conversions, when convert to a String, the system will allocate the entire amount of memory to an unique variable, and consequently you will have an memory overflow.

The best way to handle that is doing some Json Streaming, wich will read the Json in parts and parse him.

I think there's no point on reinventing the wheel, so i recommend use a Json parser library, like Gson or Jackson, they will automatically transform your json in a POJO and you can store they in a SQLite database, you can use some Database assist like a ORMLite.

This way, you can receive a huge JSON, parse him directly to a POJO Object, and insert the POJO directly to the database, leaving the memory management to the libraries.

In this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) you can parse you JSON and retrieve the entire class in a GSON or Jackson format, after that, you only need to add the ORMLite annotations and create the Database helper, it's really easy.